# Floating image between 2 columns

Tags: html, css, css-float, centering

I have a question. Does something simillar to "float: center" exist?
I am trying to make 2 columns of text and I want to have an image between them on the bottom... But not like in my example. I would like to have it floated.

Thanks for answers.

```css
.column{
  display:inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.photo{
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<p class="column">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Mauris suscipit, ligula sit amet pharetra semper, nibh ante cursus purus, vel sagittis velit mauris vel metus. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Donec vitae arcu. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. In laoreet, magna id viverra tincidunt, sem odio bibendum justo, vel imperdiet sapien wisi sed libero. Etiam dui sem, fermentum vitae, sagittis id, malesuada in, quam
</p>
<img src="http://www.matmasar.wz.cz/foto.jpg" class="photo">
<p class="column">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Mauris suscipit, ligula sit amet pharetra semper, nibh ante cursus purus, vel sagittis velit mauris vel metus. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Donec vitae arcu. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. In laoreet, magna id viverra tincidunt, sem odio bibendum justo, vel imperdiet sapien wisi sed libero. Etiam dui sem, fermentum vitae, sagittis id, malesuada in, quam
</p>
```

Comment: Can you clarify why you need the image floated? Why is your current code insufficient? You can float the image and keep it in the middle if you float the columns as well. However, as you probably noticed, that will make the image move to the top of the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

Putting your picture in a column and position it to the bottom by making the parent:

```
position: relative;
```

and the child

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

See the snippet below for the result:

```css
.column{
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.column img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<p class="column">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Mauris suscipit, ligula sit amet pharetra semper, nibh ante cursus purus, vel sagittis velit mauris vel metus. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Donec vitae arcu. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. In laoreet, magna id viverra tincidunt, sem odio bibendum justo, vel imperdiet sapien wisi sed libero. Etiam dui sem, fermentum vitae, sagittis id, malesuada in, quam
</p>
<p class="column">
<img src="http://www.matmasar.wz.cz/foto.jpg">
</p>
<p class="column">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Mauris suscipit, ligula sit amet pharetra semper, nibh ante cursus purus, vel sagittis velit mauris vel metus. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Donec vitae arcu. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. In laoreet, magna id viverra tincidunt, sem odio bibendum justo, vel imperdiet sapien wisi sed libero. Etiam dui sem, fermentum vitae, sagittis id, malesuada in, quam
</p>
```

Comment: I think I am doing something badly in describing my problem. I uploaded it to my test  [site](http://matmasar.wz.cz/kompresory.html)... the text is not floating the image....it stays in columns...it doesn´t "move" when the text hits the image area. If you know what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your question, there is no such thing as `float:center;`

In terms of your example, I think this is what you are trying to do:

```css
.column{
  float:left;
  width: 150px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.photo{
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Mauris suscipit, ligula sit amet pharetra semper, nibh ante cursus purus, vel sagittis velit mauris vel metus. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Donec vitae arcu. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. In laoreet, magna id viverra tincidunt, sem odio bibendum justo, vel imperdiet sapien wisi sed libero. Etiam dui sem, fermentum vitae, sagittis id, malesuada in, quam</p>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <img src="http://www.matmasar.wz.cz/foto.jpg" class="photo">
</div>
<div class="column">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Mauris suscipit, ligula sit amet pharetra semper, nibh ante cursus purus, vel sagittis velit mauris vel metus. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Donec vitae arcu. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. In laoreet, magna id viverra tincidunt, sem odio bibendum justo, vel imperdiet sapien wisi sed libero. Etiam dui sem, fermentum vitae, sagittis id, malesuada in, quam</p>
</div>
```

In the snippet, I removed the class of `column` from your `<p>` tags, and instead put each column inside it's own `<div>`. This causes the image to act as it's own column.

I also removed the `display:inline-block` and added `float:left` to the column class to ensure that columns appear alongside eachother.